# renode for smartfusion or smartfusion2

Tags: cortex-m

I want to simulate my application on microchip's smartfusion board with renode and SoftConsole, but I can't find a renode script about smartfusion.

I have used stm32f103.repl for smartfusion, but got many errors about memory map.

Can someone give me any help or suggestion? Thanks so much!